# Repeat line x to y every few second in php

Tags: php, javascript

how i can repeat  code from line x to y in php By Ajax.

for example:

mycode:

```
$info_2=('<div id="infobox">');
echo $chat_2;
$info_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE fuid='$uid' or luid='$uid' ");
$info_num=mysql_num_rows($info_query);
for($i=0;$i<$info_num;$i++)
{
$info_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($info_query);
echo($info_fetch['username'].':'.$info_fetch['text'].'<br>');
}
```

$info_3=('');
echo $info_3;

now i need repeat this code every x second.

Comment: Where do you `echo` the results to?

Comment: jquery ajax or simple xml httprequest..?

Comment: Similarly if I want to be repeated every few seconds, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can resolve this, is by executing [setInterval](http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/setinterval.htm) with an [Ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 
Somethine like :

```
<div id="my_container">
  </div>
  <script>
   $(function(){loadContent()}); // first time load content
   setInterval(loadContent, 2000); // every 2 seconds (2000 millis)

  function loadContent()
  {
     $.ajax({ url:'/my_content.php', 
             success(result):{$("#my_container).html(result)},
             error(result):{console.log(result.responseText)}})
   } 
  </script>
```

However, I don't like settings intervals because it does not take into account the server time.
So this is how I would do it (pseudo code):

```
 <div id="my_container">
     <!-- include content from 'my_content.php' -->
 </div>
```

Now for "my_content.php".

```
 <!--- some HTML content -->.... 
    <script>
       setTimeout(function(){$.ajax({ url:'/my_content.php', 
                                       success:function(result){ $("#my_container").html(result);},
                                        error:function(result){ console.log(result.responseText);}
                                     }})},2000) // 2 seconds since last result 
    </script>
```

This way this piece of code is "self contained" and only requires it to be wrapped with "my_container" element.